# WCF service throwing weird exception

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

after 2 days of trying to find out why my service isn't working I finally find the cause. Everytime I try to throw a new `FaultException<AuthenticationException>`, the server isn't actually throwing this but catching it itself.

So what is happening is that when I throw the exception the server is crashing with an unhandled `System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1`.

Here is my custom exception class:

```
[DataContract]
public class AuthenticationException
{
    private string validationError;

    [DataMember]
    public string ValidationError
    {
        set { validationError = value; }
        get { return validationError; }
    }

    public AuthenticationException()
    {

    }

    public AuthenticationException(string valError)
    {
        validationError = valError;
    }
}
```

And my interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthenticator
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(AuthenticationException))]
    Account authenticateApplication(string userName, string Password);
```

What can cause this?

Edit: This is how I am throwing the exception:

```
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new FaultException<AuthenticationException>(new AuthenticationException("There was a general error during the process."), new FaultReason("Error"));
            }
```

Comment: when, how are you throwing the exception? how does the server crash?

Comment: The server crashed by sending back a 500 internal server error. This is because it found an unhandled System.ServiceModel.FaultException1` like I explained above.

Comment: how are you hosting the service? IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your IIS server is not configured to allow passing exception to the client.

Follow the step 2 "Enable detailed errors for remote clients." of [this post](http://mvolo.com/troubleshoot-iis7-errors-like-a-pro/)

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple. Why was this information so hard to find? I have never seen a mention anywhere that I need to enable custom errors for exceptions to work!